# Add feet measurement option to metric based calorie calculator

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created drag bars for calorie calcular in metric system, but i want to add option for height drag bar to be both in metric (already done) and in standard feet measurement. How do I add the option in this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/018pz7nv/)

```js
$(".calculator input").on("input change", function (event) {
  var parameterName = $(this).attr("id").split("calc-")[1];
  var centimeters = $(this).val()

  switch (parameterName) {
    case "height":
      $("#calc-height_value").html("Height: " + centimeters + " cm");
      break;
    case "weight":
      var kg = $(this).val();
      $("#calc-weight_value").html("Weight: " + kg + " kg");
      break;
    case "age":
      $("#calc-age_value").html("Age: " + $(this).val());
      break;
    case "cardio":
      $("#calc-cardio_value").html("Cardio: " + $(this).val() + " hours per week");
      break;
    case "walking":
      $("#calc-walking_value").html("Walking: " + $(this).val() + " hours per week");
      break;
  }

  var height = parseInt($("#calc-height").val(), 10);
  var age = parseInt($("#calc-age").val(), 10);
  var weight = parseInt($("#calc-weight").val(), 10);
  var walking = parseInt($("#calc-walking").val(), 10);
  var cardio = parseInt($("#calc-cardio").val(), 10);
  var gender = $(".calculator input[name='gender']:checked").val();

  // The Harris–Benedict equations revised by Mifflin and St Jeor in 1990: 'A new predictive equation for resting energy expenditure in healthy individuals'
  var bmr = parseInt(10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age, 10) + (gender === "male" ? 5 : -161);
  bmr = bmr * 1.2;
  bmr += walking * 60 * (.03 * weight * 1 / 0.45) / 7;
  bmr += cardio * 60 * (.07 * weight * 1 / 0.45) / 7;
  bmr = Math.floor(bmr);

  var targetGainWeight = Math.round((bmr + 300) / 100) * 100;
  var targetMaintain = Math.round((bmr) / 100) * 100;
  var targetLoseWeight = Math.round((bmr - 500) / 100) * 100;

  $("#calc-target-gain span").html(targetGainWeight + " calories");
  $("#calc-target-maintain span").html(targetMaintain + " calories");
  $("#calc-target-lose span").html(targetLoseWeight + " calories");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bmr-calculator" class="wrapper">
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="choose-gender">
    <div class="segmented-control"><input id="calc-gender-male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"
      checked=""><label for="calc-gender-male">Male</label></div>
    <div class="segmented-control">
      <input id="calc-gender-female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><label
        for="calc-gender-female">Female</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="calc-age" id="calc-age_value">Age: 25</label>
  <input id="calc-age" type="range" value="25" min="13" max="100">
  <label for="calc-height" id="calc-height_value">Height: 180cm</label>
  <input id="calc-height" type="range" value="180" min="80" max="250">
  <label for="calc-weight" id="calc-weight_value">Weight: 80kg</label>
  <input id="calc-weight" type="range" value="80" min="40" max="200">
  <label for="calc-walking" id="calc-walking_value">Walking: 2 hours per week</label>
  <input id="calc-walking" type="range" value="2" min="0" max="50">
  <label for="calc-cardio" id="calc-cardio_value">Cardio: 1 hour per week</label>
  <input id="calc-cardio" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="50">
</div>
<div class="results">
  <div id="calc-target-gain">
    To Gain Weight:<br>
    <span>2700 calories</span>
  </div>
  <div id="calc-target-maintain">
    To Maintain:<br>
    <span>2400 calories</span>
  </div>
  <div id="calc-target-lose">
    To Lose Weight:<br>
    <span>1900 calories</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want it for the height option. I want user to be able to select just one type of height, either in cm or in feet.

Comment: You can just edit line four to: `$("#calc-height_value").html("Height: " + centimeters + " cm / " + (Math.round(centimeters / 30.48 * 100) / 100) + " feet");`. Since the formula to get feet out of centimeters is dividing cm by 30.48, all you have to do is perform that calculation on the value you already have. Then you output both above the slider bars. Here's your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/6eL3f1dr/